# The dark l sound followed by a vowel sound during linking

Tags: phonetics, ipa, dark-l

the dark L in English is at the end of a word such as "gir**l**", "penci**l**" or when it is followed by a consonant sound such as "chi**l**d".

I'm curious what is happening with the dark L during a linking scenario. Does the dark L still maintain its quality of being a dark L or just becomes a normal lighter L? I mean when one word ends in a consonant sound and next starts with a vowel sound, such as: "tel**l u**s". The words "tell" and "us" are linked.

Comment: In RP, /l/ is clear before vowels, unless it is a syllabic consonant, in which case it's varies.

Comment: I speak General American English.  I am not sure how much "linking" is a thing in my brand of English; however, I think I do lighten the /l/ in "tell us" compare with the /l/ in "tell"; however, I do not think I lighten it as far as the /l/ in "palace."  My guess is that there is marked variation among the American dialects, with some retaining a dark /l/ in all circumstances.

Comment: From English StackExchange: [L in the middle of a word: dark l or light l?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282122/l-in-the-middle-of-a-word-dark-l-or-light-l)